# reading an array with multiple items (working on two items not three)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tuples

Code below reads from a text file (containing different arrays)
and breaks down into separate elements.
I have it working fine with arrays with TWO sub items, but not a third.

For example - This file works fine:

```
('January', 2, [('curly', 30), ('larry',10), ('moe',20)])
```

.

```
staff = dict()

for item in filecontent:
    month = filecontent[0]
    section = filecontent[1]

    for name, hours in filecontent[2]:
        staff[name] = hours

print ("month:" + month)
print ("section: " + str (section))

print ("".join("%s has worked %s hours\n" % (name, hours) for name, hours in staff.items()))

overtime = int(input ("Enter overtime figure: "))

print ("".join("%s has now worked %s hours \n" % (name, (hours + overtime)) for name, hours in staff.items()))
```

But I have a different month with a *third* array element (a **bonus** figure), for example:

```
('February', 2, [('curly', 30, **10**), ('larry',10, **10** ), ('moe',20, **10**)])
```

My attempt at adapting the above code is below, but not working...

```
staff = dict()

for item in filecontent:
    month = filecontent[0]
    section = filecontent[1]

    for name, hours, bonus in filecontent[2]:
        staff[name] = hours, bonus

print ("month:" + month)
print ("section: " + str (section))

print ("".join("%s has worked %s hours with %s bonus \n" % (name, hours, bonus) for name, hours, bonus in staff.items()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
staff[name] = hours, bonus
```

You are creating a tuple:

```
>>> staff = {}
>>> hours = 40
>>> bonus = 10
>>> name = 'john'
>>> staff[name] = hours,bonus
>>> staff[name]
(40, 10)
```

So when you do `staff.items()` the result is `[('john', (40, 10))]`. To print this:

```
print(''.join('{0} has worked {1} hours with {2} bonus'.format(x, *y) for x,y in staff.items()))
```

The `*y` passes the expanded (exploded) tuple to the format function, which then maps it to the second and third arguments.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check the length of the element before applying your algorithm.
using `len()`

```
for element in filecontent[2]:
   if len(element) == 3:
      name, hours, bonus = element
      ## do other stuff

   else: 
      name, hours = element
```

**EDIT**
I would suggest if you do not want this solution, you can have the file contents (if you have control over that or you can change it) return always 3 elements where 0 is the default if you have no bonus.